# How to dealloc a UIView while one of its subviews is animating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, memory-leaks

[image] --------> [image]

I am attempting to create a custom [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/). The custom view should behave the exactly the same as the standard view, except the image that it spins looks different. I noticed that my custom view would not deallocate when it is removed from its superview in the following test code:

```
ActivityIndicatorCustomView* v = [[ActivityIndicatorCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:v];
[v removeFromSuperview];
```

The culprit is the animation block, because when it is commented out, dealloc will be called. I believe it is a retain cycle, but I don't see how to solve the issue.

**ActivityIndicatorCustomView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ActivityIndicatorCustomView : UIView

@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL isAnimating;

- (void)startAnimating;
- (void)stopAnimating;

@end
```

**ActivityIndicatorCustomView.m**

```
static const NSTimeInterval ANIMATION_PERIOD_HALF_LIFE = 1.0f;

#import "ActivityIndicatorCustomView.h"

@interface ActivityIndicatorCustomView ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imageView;
@property(nonatomic, assign, readwrite) BOOL isAnimating;

- (void)animateWithTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform;

@end

@implementation ActivityIndicatorCustomView

#pragma mark NSObject

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}

#pragma mark UIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"activityIndicatorCustom"]];
        self.imageView.frame = self.bounds;
        [self addSubview:self.imageView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    if (!self.hidden && self.superview != nil) {
        [self startAnimating];
    }
}

- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
{    
    if (newSuperview == nil) {
        [self stopAnimating];
    }
}

- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden
{
    if (hidden) {
        [self stopAnimating];
    } else if (self.superview != nil) {
        [self startAnimating];
    }

    [super setHidden:hidden];
}

#pragma mark ActivityIndicatorCustomView 

- (void)startAnimating
{
    if (self.isAnimating) {
        return;
    }

    self.isAnimating = YES;
    [self animateWithTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI)];
}

- (void)stopAnimating
{
    [self.imageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    self.isAnimating = NO;
}

#pragma mark ()

- (void)animateWithTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
{
    // Must split the animation into two semi-circles. If 
    // you attempt to rotate a full circle, nothing will
    // happen.
    __block ActivityIndicatorCustomView* weakSelf = self;

    [UIView
        animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_PERIOD_HALF_LIFE
        delay:0.0
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
        animations:^{
            weakSelf.imageView.transform = transform;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [weakSelf animateWithTransform:CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(transform)
                ? CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI)
                : CGAffineTransformIdentity
            ];
        }
    ];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was following a [bad tutorial](http://benscheirman.com/2012/01/careful-with-block-based-notification-handlers/) on retain cycles in blocks. It told me to do

```
__block MyViewController *weakSelf = self;
```

This is wrong. To create a weak reference, I should do this instead:

```
__weak ActivityIndicatorCustomView* weakSelf = self;

[UIView
    animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_PERIOD_HALF_LIFE
    delay:0.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
    animations:^{
        weakSelf.imageView.transform = transform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [weakSelf animateWithTransform:CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(transform)
            ? CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI)
            : CGAffineTransformIdentity
        ];
    }
];
```

Comment: Under manual reference counting, a `__block` didn't retain.  Under ARC, it does.

Comment: The tutorial was published on Jan 11th, 2012. I guess that was before the time of ARC.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you continue animating (and retain `self` in next [self animateWithTransform:] call) in the completion block. Try, for example, checking for the superview to decide whether to continue animating:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (self.superview) {
            [self animateWithTransform:CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(transform)
                ? CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI)
                : CGAffineTransformIdentity
            ];
         }
    }
```